# git diff produces incorrect patch

Tags: git, kotlin, diff, patch

I'm trying to produce a patch from a git tag `A` and `master` and to then apply the patch as a single commit to a separate branch `B` (whose last commit is tagged `A`).

I believe `git` is missing something when generating the patch that causes it to not apply cleanly.

The file `it/my/application/Something.kt` in question contains code similar to:

```kotlin
package it.my.application

import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
import it.my.application.SomethingFacade
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

typealias Something = Int
```

in `master` the file was renamed to `other/my/application/Something.kt` and changed to:

```kotlin
package other.my.application

import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton
import javax.transaction.Transactional

typealias SomethingId = Int
```

Note:

- the line `package it.my.application` was changed to `package other.my.application`
- the line `import it.my.application.SomethingFacade` was removed
- the line `import javax.transaction.Transactional` was added

Looking at the patch these is the hunk that `git` generates for this portion of the code:

```
diff --git a/src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt b/src/main/kotlin/other/my/application/Something.kt
similarity index 91%
rename from src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt
rename to src/main/kotlin/other/my/application/Something.kt
index ed24736..cb13606 100644
--- a/src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt
+++ b/src/main/kotlin/other/my/application/Something.kt
@@ -1,10 +1,11 @@
-package it.my.application
+package other.my.application
 
 import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
 import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
 import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 import javax.inject.Singleton
+import javax.transaction.Transactional
 
 typealias SomethingId = Int
```

As you can see from this hunk:

- the change of the `package` line is properly reported
- the addition of the `Transactional` import is properly reported
- **no mention of the removal of the `SomethingFacade` line!**

When trying to apply the patch `git` fails saying that "it does not match"..

I tried generating the patch with `-C 2/1/0` and they all fail in some way or another (Note: I'm generating a single patch for the whole directory. With `-C 0` I believe this file works but countless other files do not).

I can do `git apply --3way` and fix stuff manually, but doing this the problem does not get actually caught... the result is:

```kotlin
package other.my.application

import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
import it.my.application.SomethingFacade
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton
import javax.transaction.Transactional

typealias SomethingId = Int
```

So the line about `SomethingFacade` is left behind. This is the output of the merge for this file:

```
Checking patch src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt => src/main/kotlin/other/my/application/Something.kt...
error: while searching for:
package it.my.application

import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

typealias SomethingId = Int


error: patch failed: src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt:1
Falling back to three-way merge...
```

---

Shouldn't `git` generate either:

```
--- a/src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt
+++ b/src/main/kotlin/other/my/application/Something.kt
@@ -1,10 +1,11 @@
-package it.my.application
+package other.my.application
 
 import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
 import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
 import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
-import it.my.application.SomethingFacade
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 import javax.inject.Singleton
+import javax.transaction.Transactional
 
 typealias SomethingId = Int
```

or something like:

```
--- a/src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt
+++ b/src/main/kotlin/other/my/application/Something.kt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-package it.my.application
+package other.my.application
 
 import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener
@@ -4,7 +4,8 @@
 import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener
 import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.TransactionalEventListener.TransactionPhase
-import it.my.application.SomethingFacade
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
@@ -7,10 +8,11 @@
 import javax.inject.Singleton
+import javax.transaction.Transactional
 
 typealias SomethingId = Int
```

?

Why does it simply ignore the `SomethingFacade` line?

---

Additional information (not sure whether this is relevant):

The `A` tag is on a previous commit of the `master` branch whose contents are identical to the HEAD of the `B` branch. The `B` branch was created from a previous version of `master` where all the commits were squashed into a single commit.

The point of branch `B` is that it should hide the commit activity & authors of the original commits. We periodically sync `master` with `B` by squashing all new commits into a single commit in `B`. So branch `B` and `master` do not have a common history **but** for every commit of `B` there is a commit of `master` whose content is identical.
I'm not sure whether this creates an issue with `git diff`... I have successfully used this approach in other code bases without issues.

Answer (score 1):

To get that particular diff output, the files that diff is comparing here must have those particular texts as inputs.  That is, the *pair* of files that `git diff` is comparing here *don't* have `import it.my.application.SomethingFacade` in *either file*.

Note that you can view the two files being compared, as their blob hash IDs are given by the `index` line:

> ```
> index ed24736..cb13606 100644
> ```

The left-side file is Git internal blob `ed24736` and right right-side file is Git internal blob `cb13606`.

(These two different files may be contained in many different commits, since Git de-duplicates the committed copies that appear in each commit.  So there is no telling which *commits* are being compared here; all we know, from the `git diff` output, is which *blob objects* are being compared.  But your `git diff` command will usually specify the two commits to be compared: in

```
git diff <hash1> <hash2>
```

for instance, the two `hash`-es present here are the hash IDs of the commits in question.

If you are using tag names, e.g.:

```
git diff v1.2 v3.4
```

you can have Git resolve the tag names to commit hash IDs, if you'd like, with `git rev-parse v1.2` and `git rev-parse v3.4`.  Either way, though, we know from the actual `git diff` output that the *files* being compared have the two given blob hash IDs.

Comment: The patch is produced by `git diff --patch A..master`. Doing `git checkout A` the file **does** contain that line. I wonder: is there any difference between using `A..master` and `A master` as two separate arguments?

Comment: @GACy20: no: `A..master` and `A master` should resolve exactly the same way for `git diff`. If it does not, you've hit the (unlikely but possible) case where there is an actual bug in Git, and if the repository in question is available to the general public, you could send a reproducer to the Git mailing list with a bug report.

Comment: Does the fact that the branch `B` and `master` have no common ancestor in terms of commits have any relevance? I'm tempted to try and use plain `diff` by copying the repository in 2 different directories to generate the patch...

Comment: If you mean in terms of the `git diff --patch`, no. Normally, the lack of a common ancestor would mean that `A..master` (or `B..master`, or `master..B`, or whatever) was kind of meaningless, but in `git diff` it just takes the internal result of `git rev-parse` and notices that it came out as `^<rev-of-A> <rev-of-master>` and uses the negated one as the left side and the non-negated one as the right. Diff treats `X...Y` internally similarly: that becomes ^<each merge base> <X>|LEFT <Y>|RIGHT and picks one of the bases as the left side and <Y> as the right.

Comment: If you mean in terms of *applying the resulting patch*, then of course the actual source matters, as do the presence of any `index` lines and whether the blob(s) listed in those index lines exist in the repository. When you get `error: patch failed: src/main/kotlin/it/my/application/Something.kt:1
Falling back to three-way merge...` this means the merge *didn't* apply as-is, and Git needs to find the original file, apply the patch to it, and use that as the `theirs` in a three-way merge.